# InvitationID null in production but not in the same apk installed manually

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I have a very strange beaviour in my game.
First of all, I have two version: paid and free, linked in same play service ID.

I developed and try the apps, and they work perfectly, so I put them in production, on google play.
Then I discover by feedback that the paid version, when accept the invitation, don't handle, becouse it's null!
In the free version instead, it works fine.
THE CODE IS THE SAME.

How is possible?

The same APK installed manually works, then put on google play doesn't works.

Anyone has this problem?

This is the code:

```
    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        super.onSignInSucceeded();
        Log.i(GameProps.TAG, "invitation: "+getInvitationId());
        if (getInvitationId()!=null) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this, OnlineGameScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra(GameProps.INVITATION_ID, getInvitationId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

getInvitationId() return null.
How it is possibile?

Bye.

Comment: Is this happening for 100% of users? Can you repro the problem on your device? If so, can you attach logs?

Comment: It happens to 100% of device that download the app from play store. If instead install the app manually this doesn't happens.
The log doesn't say more...
Simply when user accept the invitation, the getInvitationId return null in play store version, instead of invitation id returned by the same apk installed manually.
I don't know what I can to do.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have enabled Anti-Piracy in Developer Console, right? If so, could you try disabling?

Comment: Hi Bruno. No, my apps have Anti-Piracy disabled. I don't understand why it's happening, but I try all, and my code is the same in free and paid version. The paid version work only with apk installed manually, once it goes on playstore it doesn't works. My app is in production, what I can do? If you want I send you the entire code (very small) of the activity that should receive the invitation. Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.
The code before is changed with this:

```
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    super.onSignInSucceeded();
    getGamesClient().loadInvitations(new OnInvitationsLoadedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInvitationsLoaded(int statusCode, InvitationBuffer buffer) {
            ArrayList<Long> timestamps=new ArrayList<Long>(); 
            for (Invitation invitation:buffer) {
                timestamps.add(invitation.getCreationTimestamp());
            }
            Collections.sort(timestamps);
            if (!timestamps.isEmpty()) {
                for (Invitation invitation:buffer) {
                    Log.i(GameProps.TAG, "invitation buffer: "+invitation.getInvitationId());
                    if (invitation.getCreationTimestamp()==timestamps.get(timestamps.size()-1)) {
                        invitationId=invitation.getInvitationId();
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.i(GameProps.TAG, "invitation: "+invitationId);
            if (invitationId!=null) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainScreen.this, OnlineGameScreen.class);
                intent.putExtra(GameProps.INVITATION_ID, invitationId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So I have to say that GooglePlayGames lib is buggy, becouse getInvitationId() doesn't work correctly.
Expecially becouse it works if apk is installed manually, and not for app downloaded from playstore.

It's happend with 2 of 4 of my apps, so I think it will remain a mistery.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem... I'm still puzzled at why this is happening. On your production app, if you enable debug logs with BaseGameActivity.enableDebugLogs(), do you get a line in logcat that reads "onConnected: connection hint provided. Checking for invite."?